# Java - Convert a String to a series of images.

Tags: user-interface

I created a game that uses a map. The map is a string and looks something like this -

```
######
#....#
#..I.#
#.T..#
######
```

Where # = wall, I,T = items, and dots = space.

I'm now trying to construct a GUI and I'd like to show the map as a series of little images. For example each # will be represented by a wall icon. Is there anyway of converting this to a series of little icons? Would it be better to convert the String into a 2D array?

Thanks a lot!